# Why is IFormFile showing null, and how do I fix it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET 5, MVC 6 in VS 2015. I am making a web application. On my form I have:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="uploadSection" >
        <label >Select files for upload</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileSelect" name="fileSelect" multiple />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="thisbutton" value="button"  />
    </div>
    </form>
```

in my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileForm(FileViewModel vm, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //IFormFileCollection files = Request.Form.Files;
            string filePath = Path.Combine("C:", "transfers");
            //foreach (var file in files)
            //{
                if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    await file.SaveAsAsync(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName));
                }
            //}
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I have a much larger form with mother form fields in it that are going into my FormViewModel (ALL fields are populating as they should), and I actually tried putting the IFormFileCollection, ICollection, IList, List as the parameters in the method above and instead also putting it directly in my view model. Whether I do it as a single file or multiple, in the model or the controller, I always get null. 
The 'IFormFileCollecion files = Request.Form.Files' actually works, but I don't want to do it that way because it should work the way I have or had it. 
When I put the property for the files in my model, I put "[Required]" above it and it doesn't trigger.

AND, even better, I ran this multiple times with fiddler and it is actually POSTING the files-- so why aren't they being cast into the model?

Do I have my dependencies wrong? Can anyone think of what could cause this?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http":  "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Your file input has a name attribute of "fileSelect".  The name of your parameter to your action is "file".  Make them match and it should work.

Comment: That did it. I didn't even realize I wasn't using an ID on all my other form fields, I was using asp-for. I had the name/id on this because I had a jQuery function i was testing with it. Thank you.

Comment: This is also true when submitting a file through ajax: `formData.append("file", file);`   It took me many hours to resolve this issue. The name of the parameter in the action must match the name which is submitted. Otherwise, the controller will process the request, but the parameter will be null

Answer (score 1):

might sounds simple! but in addition to same `//name// @model-view-controller`, check the `form.serialize();` caused me 24hrs to find this!