# IFormFile always returns Null value on dotnet core 2.0

Tags: c#, file, .net-core, cloudinary

I have a post request for my `PhotosController` class. When I test this code, it always returns a null value. I don't see file details. 
Basically it gets the `userid` and `PhotoDto` and it should return photo. I use `Cloudinary` service to store photos. My API settings of the clodinary is located inside `appsettings.json` file and there is no problem for those settings. When I debug the code, the problem occurs where `if (file.Length > 0)` is. I am guessing that there is no file.

Here is my `PhotoForCreationDto` file:

```
public class PhotoForCreationDto
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public string PublicId { get; set; }

    public PhotoForCreationDto()
    {
        DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And here is my `PhotosController` file:

```
    [Authorize]
[Route("api/users/{userId}/photos")]
public class PhotosController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDatingRepository _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IOptions<CloudinarySettings> _cloudinaryConfig;
    private Cloudinary _cloudinary;

    public PhotosController(IDatingRepository repo,
        IMapper mapper,
        IOptions<CloudinarySettings> cloudinaryConfig)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repo = repo;
        _cloudinaryConfig = cloudinaryConfig;

        Account acc = new Account(
            _cloudinaryConfig.Value.CloudName,
            _cloudinaryConfig.Value.ApiKey,
            _cloudinaryConfig.Value.ApiSecret
        );

        _cloudinary = new Cloudinary(acc);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPhoto")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPhoto(int id)
    {
        var photoFromRepo = await _repo.GetPhoto(id);

        var photo = _mapper.Map<PhotoForReturnDto>(photoFromRepo);

        return Ok(photo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddPhotoForUser(int userId, PhotoForCreationDto photoDto)
    {
        var user = await _repo.GetUser(userId);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest("Could not find user");

        var currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

        if (currentUserId != user.Id)
            return Unauthorized();

        var file = photoDto.File;

        var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();

        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                {
                    File = new FileDescription(file.Name, stream)
                };

                uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
            }
        }

        photoDto.Url = uploadResult.Uri.ToString();
        photoDto.PublicId = uploadResult.PublicId;

        var photo = _mapper.Map<Photo>(photoDto);

        photo.User = user;

        if (!user.Photos.Any(m => m.IsMain))
            photo.IsMain = true;

        user.Photos.Add(photo);



        if (await _repo.SaveAll())
        {
            var photoToReturn = _mapper.Map<PhotoForReturnDto>(photo);
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetPhoto", new { id = photo.Id }, photoToReturn);
        }

        return BadRequest("Could not add the photo");
    }
}
```

Here is error at postman:

[image]
I tried to use `[FromBody]` but it also didn't work. 
I would appriciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325854/why-is-iformfile-showing-null-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: This doesn't help because I don't have frontend yet. I test it with postman. Also, file attribute matches.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce your problem. I'm using your code and sending the same query from Postman, `File` property in `photoDto` is set correctly. Try debugging the code and check what is the value of `ModelState.IsValid`. I also see that you filled 2 headers in the request. What are the headers and which values do you send? One of them is probably `Authorization`, which is the other?

Comment: @CodeFuller I used content-type: application/json header. This was the problem. I removed and It worked. Move your comment to solution so that I accept your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When submitting file from Postman, make sure you don't fill `Content-Type` header by yourself. Postman will set it automatically to `multipart/form-data` value.

Setting `Content-Type` header to `application/json` prevents ASP.Net Core from correct processing of request data. That's why `IFormFile` property is not filled and is set to `null`.