# formData is always null when arriving in API core 3.1

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

Trying to upload an image to my backend using FormData. file inside my API is always null when using my angular code.

Creating FormData:

```
upload() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', this.editedImage);
    console.log("editedImage: " + this.editedImage);
    console.log("formdata: " + formData);

    this.imageService.create(formData).subscribe(response => {
      let temp = response;
      console.log(temp);
    })
}
```

Service that does the post call:

```
create(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    console.log("formdata in service: " + formData.get('upload'));
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}`, formData).pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('Image verstuurd: ' + data)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

API that receives it:

```
[HttpPost]
async public Task<ActionResult> Save([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    // Get reference to blob
    var uniqueName = $@"{Guid.NewGuid()}-{file.FileName}";
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueName);

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    file.CopyTo(ms);
    var stream = ms.ToArray();

    await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(stream, 0, stream.Length);

    return Json(new
    {
        name = blockBlob.Name,
        uri = blockBlob.Uri
    });
}
```

It works when I upload an image using Postman, not when using the angular code.

EDIT:

The correct answer was found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35325907/7128762

The problem is basicly that I needed to give my IFormFile the correct name in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

[FromForm] is going to try to build a reference type for the form data it receives so your FormFile needs to be inside of a reference type you define.

Set up your model with something like this:

```
public class YourDataModel 
{
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
   // whatever other properties you need
}
```

Try something like this in your API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
async public Task<ActionResult> Save([FromForm]YourDataModel file)
{
   // your logic
}
```

Comment: I was so happy to see an answer, however same issue. Made the model like you said, I don't need anything else so only a IFormFile prop. Still null