# Appended FormData sends the null value to the API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I have used `ngx-image-cropper` in my Angular project for cropping images before uploading. Some related parts of **component.ts** are:

```
croppedImage: any = '';
imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
  this.croppedImage = event.base64;
}
Base64ToFile(url: any, filename: any, mimeType: any){
    return (fetch(url)
            .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
            .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], filename,{type:mimeType});})
        );
  }

 OnSubmit() {
    const filedata = new FormData();
    this.Base64ToFile(this.croppedImage, "myphoto.png", "image/png").then(function(outputFile){
      
      console.log(outputFile);
      filedata.append("file", outputFile, outputFile.name);//The first parameter "file" is the input parameter in API method
    });
    this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/featuredpost/postimage/' + this.selectedPostId, filedata).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
  }
```

**API action:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostImage([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromRoute] int id){
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when I debug my API, the input `file` parameter is null while `cropped image` has a `base64` string value. How can I fix it?
I searched for related questions but did not find any solution to my case.
[A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989200/formdata-is-always-null-when-arriving-in-api-core-3-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.http.post` needs to be in a `.then(...)` of the `this.Base64ToFile(..)` call

You're not waiting for the `async` `fetch` to complete before the API `post`